# How to speed up slicing in python, not using the for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, pytorch, slice

I'm trying to speed up the following python code:

```
import torch
import numpy as np

A = torch.zeros(11, 16, 64)
B = torch.randn(11, 9, 64)

indices = np.random.randint(0,9,(11,16))

for i in range(len(A)):
    A[i,:,:] = B[i,indices[i],:]
```

Is there a nice way not to use the for loop? This way, it is really slow, especially when dealing with the big data . The indices is the pre-defined 2-dim matrix with size (11,16). What I need is to assign the elements of B to A according to the order of indices. After the speeding up, the result of A should be exactly the same with mine resulted A. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple mult-dimensional indices but they need to be the same size or broadcastable. So for example

```
# create a (11, 1) range array that broadcasts with indices which is (11, 16)
indices0 = np.expand_dims(np.arange(indices.shape[0]), 1)
A = B[indices0, indices, :]
```

Since broadcasting can be confusing I'll try to explain this a little. Basically you want `indices0` and `indices` to be the same size and represent pairs of indices of B. The first index will be stored in `indices0` and the second will be stored in `indices` in corresponding locations. Broadcasting implicitly repeats the columns of `indices0` to make it the same shape as `indices` and can often be faster than constructing the full sized `indices0`.

In case it helps here are some more verbose examples demonstrating why this works:

```
import torch
import numpy as np

B = torch.randn(11, 9, 64)
indices = np.random.randint(0,9,(11,16))

# constructing indices0 more verbosely (and slower) for demonstration purposes
a0, a1 = indices.shape
a2 = B.shape[2]

# construct a complete indices0 the slow way, the same size as indices
indices0 = np.empty((a0, a1), dtype=np.int32)
for i in range(a0):
    for j in range(a1):
        indices0[i,j] = i

# version 1 (nothing complicated happening here but very slow)
A1 = torch.empty(a0, a1, a2, dtype=B.dtype)
for i in range(a0):
    for j in range(a1):
        A1[i,j,:] = B[indices0[i,j], indices[i,j], :]

# version 2 (using advanced indexing without broadcasting)
A2 = B[indices0, indices, :]

# version 3 (with broadcasting)
# remove repeated columns leaving indices0 as (11, 1) the same state as above
indices0 = indices0[:, :1]
# broadcasting implicitly repeats columns of indices0 to match indices
A3 = B[indices0, indices, :]

# version 4 (your method)
A4 = torch.empty(a0, a1, a2, dtype=B.dtype)
for i in range(a0):
    A4[i,:,:] = B[i,indices[i],:]

# compare everything    
error = torch.sum(torch.abs(A1 - A2)).item() + \
        torch.sum(torch.abs(A2 - A3)).item() + \
        torch.sum(torch.abs(A3 - A4)).item()
print('Error:', error)
```

which prints

```
Error: 0.0
```

demonstrating that all these methods are equivalent.

---

Also, if you wanted to stay in the PyTorch framework and `indices` were a `torch.LongTensor` instead of a `numpy.ndarray` then you could use

```
indices0 = torch.arange(indices.shape[0]).unsqueeze(1)
A = B[indices0, indices, :]
```

Answer (score -1):

Slicing using numpy is fast enough even for Machine Learning projects. If you want to make your code run faster in this case, you should use this:

```
A_length = len(A)
i = 0
while i < A_length:
    A[i,:,:] = B[i,indices[i],:]
    i += 1
```

A `range` object uses `__iter__` and `__next__` method to generate the iteration index (for most cases), even if it's written in C, it's slower than just declare a index counter, and add step to it every round.

But `for` loop is more readable and simple for your code, plus using `while` loop won't increase the speed that much. I don't think you should use `while` loop for a tiny speed increasement.

But...

If you want your code run as fast as it can:

1. Learn some performance trick
2. Consider using ssh and GPU remote server. They are much much faster than your CPU (if you're using CPU computer)
3. Learn C or JS, they are compiled languages. C is about 200 times faster than python without optimization, and about 50000 times faster with multi-core processing and multi-thread (from [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLUl4u3cNGP63VIBQVWguXxZZi0566y7Wf))